# unixodbc and freetds setup on OSX and Rails 2.3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, macos, unixodbc, iodbc

I'm trying to set up unixodbc on OSX (10.7.3), but it looks like iODBC is on the way.

My config/database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  encoding: UTF8
  mode: odbc
  username: user
  password: passwd
  dsn: MY_DSN
```

ruby-obdc is installed and in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'ruby-odbc', :require => 'odbc_utf8'
```

/usr/local/etc/freetds.conf:

```
[MY_SERVER]
host = host.bla.com
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
```

/usr/local/etc/odbc.ini

```
[MY_DSN]
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Description=Sql Server Local
Servername=MY_SERVER
Port=1433
Database=my_database
```

When I run `script/console` and try to access any model:

> > Product
> >        ODBC::Error: IM002 (0) [iODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified. Driver could not be loaded

It seems iODBC is being used to connect to the database, when I want to use unixodbc. How can I make my rails app use unixodbc instead of iODBC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by compiling ruby-odbc against Homebrew libraries. This works if you are on OSX:

```
gem install ruby-odbc -- --with-odbc-lib=/usr/local/lib
```

Comment: can you be more specific? i'm having this issue and this doesn't exactly give a step by step solution.  thanks

Comment: What OS are you running? I installed unixodbc using Brew and then linked it using this on OSX.

Comment: It was my ruby on mac os x i posted a solution to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

iODBC, maintained and supported by [my employer](http://www.openlinksw.com/), has shipped as part of Mac OS X since Jaguar (10.2.x).

You'll be better off [updating iODBC with all the latest patches](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/Downloads#Mac_OS_X) (Apple tends to be a bit behind on these), than shifting to UnixODBC.  You may also find some benefit in the [Ruby+ODBC](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/IODBCRubyHOWTO#MacOS_X) and [Ruby-on-Rails](http://odbc-rails.rubyforge.org/) docs we've published.

Last, it's best to keep all your ODBC configuration in the default file locations for Mac OS X --

```
/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini
/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini
/Users/*/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini
/Users/*/Library/ODBC/odbcinst.ini
```

You can create symlinks from anywhere else you may want to have these files, e.g. --

```
ln -s ~/Library/ODBC/odbc.ini ~/.odbc.ini
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately I don't need to use odbc anymore. Still, I hope people having problems with unixodbc can use your post to solve their issues. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Homebrew. Needed to use:

```
gem install ruby-odbc -- --with-odbc-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.2
```

I didn't notice this earlier but in Pedro's answer he has `with-odbc-lib`. not sure if that works for his environment, but i needed this to be `dir`, because i kept getting a checking for sql.h... no error.