# Unable to get unixODBC working on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, odbc, unixodbc

I am trying to connect to Microsoft MySQL server from a Mac.Debugging it step by step (I basically follow [this](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2013/01/installing-debugging-odbc-on-mac-os-x/comment-page-1/#comment-260912) post)I see that freeTDS works fine.But isql shows an error -

> [S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
>   [01000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unknown host machine name.
>   [ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect

I installed freetds using Macports with

sudo port install freetds +mssql +odbc +universal

and created my own odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files under /opt/local/etc (contents are same as what is shown in the above mentioned link )

I also checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925843/unixodbc-and-freetds-setup-on-osx-and-rails-2-3-x) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872340/odbc-unable-to-connect-to-mssql-data-source-on-os-x-lion) (Not sure how un-install can help when I installed freetds with +odbc).Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone bumps into this I figured out the solution-

Turns out the configuration name provided under freeTDS.conf had to precisely match the one in odbc.ini.